# Elements are bumping into each other in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm building a website in Bootstrap but when I switch my website to a mobile responsive view some elements are bumping into each other like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFel8.png).

That's how site looks in the [large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFDaK.png) version.

I'm tried to add some media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    /*Intro*/
    .title {
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .title-text {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .title-btn button {
        padding: 10px 35px !important;
    }
}
```

But elements still are bumping into each other when I switch to mobile responsive view.

My HTML code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- Intro -->
    <section class="intro" id="intro">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 order-1 order-lg-2">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="Img/Intro/Phone.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-lg-6 order-2 order-lg-1 title-block">
                        <div class="pre-title">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-award" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M9.669.864L8 0 6.331.864l-1.858.282-.842 1.68-1.337 1.32L2.6 6l-.306 1.854 1.337 1.32.842 1.68 1.858.282L8 12l1.669-.864 1.858-.282.842-1.68 1.337-1.32L13.4 6l.306-1.854-1.337-1.32-.842-1.68L9.669.864zm1.196 1.193l.684 1.365 1.086 1.072L12.387 6l.248 1.506-1.086 1.072-.684 1.365-1.51.229L8 10.874l-1.355-.702-1.51-.229-.684-1.365-1.086-1.072L3.614 6l-.25-1.506 1.087-1.072.684-1.365 1.51-.229L8 1.126l1.356.702 1.509.229z"/>
                                <path d="M4 11.794V16l4-1 4 1v-4.206l-2.018.306L8 13.126 6.018 12.1 4 11.794z"/>
                            </svg>
                            <p>#1 Editiors Choice App of 2020</p>
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="title">
                            Best app for your
                            modern lifestyle
                        </h1>
                        <p class="title-text">
                            Increase productivity with a simple to-do app. app for
                            managing your personal budgets.
                        </p>    
                        <div class="title-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Try for free
                            </button>
                            <a href="#" class="title-link">Watch demo video</a>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </section>

    <!-- Features -->
    <section class="features" id="features">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="companies">
                <p class="companies-text">Trusted by companies like</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row companies-logos">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <img src="Img/Companies/SouthWest.png " class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <img src="Img/Companies/Anubis.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <img src="Img/Companies/Alonzo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <img src="Img/Companies/Express.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <img src="Img/Companies/Maniac.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that looks like structure of HTML in your footer section. Initializing the row div, you should have used "col" feature as you used. Your code looks like the same what I explain. However, there is a little bit difference compare to what i mention. In order to make it clear for you, i have build up this snippet for you. You need to use "col" feature on element that you want to layout . In your code, you used for container of image tags which is not the element you want to make it responsive. That is why you got bumping into each other. I wish that yoou figure it out. Cheers!

```css
.box{
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box-1{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.box-2{
  background-color: purple;
}
.box-3{
  background-color: blue;
}
.box-4{
  background-color: green;
}
.box-5{
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>stackover</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="features" id="features">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="companies">
          <p class="companies-text">Trusted by companies like</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row companies-logos">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 box box-1">Logo-1</div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 box box-2">Logo-2</div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 box box-3">Logo-3</div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 box box-4">Logo-4</div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 box box-5">Logo-5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably, I don't understood you clearly, but I tried to use funtion "col"  on img tag  directly like this:  `<div class="row companies-logos">
         <div>
          <img src="Img/Companies/SouthWest.png" alt="" class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
         </div>
        </div>`        Bur I still have the same problem

Comment: <div class="row companies-logos">
   <img src="Img/Companies/SouthWest.png" alt="" class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-2"> 
</div>  try like this. It works on my dev tool. If it still does not work, You should give new width and height to your images in order to have horizontal layout on the footer. Also dont change the code that ı put on the comment. Hope you that you understood.